# How to reference dictionary value without iterating in Jinja2 template?

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

Am attempting to reference a specific dictionary value in my Jinja2 template, but it seems it only allows me to reference with integer indices instead of the named key.

Here is my Flask/Python3.6 code:

```
data_dict = {"saved_selections": {}, "records": 0}
for row in cursor.fetchall():
    data_dict["saved_selections"].update({"question" + row[1]: row[2]})
```

The data in row is 3 columns (confirmed). Index 1 is an ID field, and index 2 is the value I want to store.

In my html template, I have tried:

> "data_dict" is returned in a function and stored in variable called
>   "data" which is returned in the "render_template" function.

```
<option value="Not Reviewed" {% if data[0][0][2]=="Not Reviewed" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>Not Reviewed</option>
```

and:

```
<option value="Not Reviewed" {% if data['saved_selections']['question1'][2]=="Not Reviewed" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>Not Reviewed</option>
```

When I attempt the named key way, I get the error:

> jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: dict object has no element 'saved_selections'

Here is some of the sample data returned in my query if useful:

```
LatestRound ReviewItemTaskID    ReviewItemValue
6           2                   Yes
6           3                   Yes
6           4   
6           5                   No - Provided Training
6           6                   No - Requested Update
```

I'm ultimately just trying to return a dictionary that has each row's values in it (under a single key named "saved_selections"), another key named "records" that will store the total rows returned, and then be able to reference them in my template without needing to iterate with a for loop.

EDIT: thought it would be helpful to add what I'm wanting my data to look like:

```
data_dict = {
    "saved_selections": {
        "question1": "Yes",
        "question2": "Not Reviewed",
        "question3": "No - Provided Training"
    },
    "records": 3
}
```

EDIT 2: Here is the view function where data is defined and returned:

```
@app.route("/main", methods=["POST"])
def main_page():
    data = (c.getReviewData(location=request.form['location'])
    return render_template("main.html", data=data, location=location)
```

Comment: Python dictionaries are unordered. They do not have set indices. You access them by their key to get the value. If you store `data_dict` as a list or OrderedDict instead of a dict then you can access it by its indices since it has order. Also in your html template you are using `data` instead of `data_dict` it seems.

Comment: Yes - sorry, I will update OP. data_dict is returned in a function and stored in variable called "data" which is returned in the "render_template" function.

Comment: Is your value stored in `question2` always the value you want to be doing the comparison on in the template?

Comment: for that particular select dropdown, yes, "question2"s value is what I will always use for that comparison. For the "question3" select dropdown, I would use the value in "question3" key for the comparison.

Comment: Then you should be accessing the data dict like `data['saved_selections']['question2']=='Not Reviewed'` in your template. Because whatever you are doing with the [2] at the end of your accessing the value is not correct.

Comment: I agree! I think Joost may be on to something though.. I think the template side may be ok, but it may not be receiving what I expect it to be getting. I'm probably doing something wrong with my declaration of "data" in my route definition, and/or the way I'm returning it to the template.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is likely something wrong with your `data_dict`. Perhaps your overwriting it somewhere, or retuning the wrong dict to jinja.

First this

```
<option value="Not Reviewed" {% if data['saved_selections']=="banana" %} selected="selected"{% endif %}>Not Reviewed</option>
```

In combinations with this `render_template`

```
return render_template('test.html', data={'saved_selections': 'banana'})
```

To ensure that your dict is correct.

But we need to see the entire flask route in order to find the issue here.

Comment: Added EDIT 2 to original post.

Comment: what does `data` look like if you print it in the flask route itself?

Comment: Being brand new to Flask and Python, I feel pretty dumb not knowing exactly how to do that... I added a sys.stderr print statement and got: "{ "status": "must be str, not int" }
"

Comment: `data = (c.getReviewData(location=request.form['location'])`, `print(data)`, `return render_template("main.html", data=data, location=location)`

Comment: OK, i think my main issue was in "data_dict["saved_selections"].update({"question" + row[1]: row[2]})"... I had to wrap row[1] in str() to be able to concat that. Now it appears I'm at least getting a dictionary result.